# grep for lines/files that contain exactly X chars

Tags: terminal, grep, regular-expression

Here's the output of a `grep` command I ran:

```
[user@localhost] : ~/Documents/challenge $ grep -i -e ".\{32\}" fileA fileB
fileA:W0mMhUcRRnG8dcghE4qvk3JA9lGt8nDl
fileB:observacion = new Observacion();
fileB:observacion.setCodigoOf(ordenBO.getCodigo());
fileB:observacion.setDetalle(of.getObservacion().getSolicitante());
fileB:observacion.setTipoObservacion(TipoObservacionOrdenFleteMaestro.SOLICITANTE);
fileB:observacion.setProceso(TipoProcesoObservacionMaestro.MODIFICACION);
fileB:observacion.setFecha(Utiles.getFechaSistema());
fileB:java.util.Date fechaHora = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
fileB:observacion.setUsuarioCrecion(usuarioSesionado.getUsuario().getUsuario());
fileB:daoObservacion.agregaObservacion(observacion);
```

I'm looking for 32 character long string in two files: `fileA` and `fileB`. 
Importantly, `fileA` contains exactly 32 characters only, with no line breaks:

```
[user@localhost] : ~/Documents/challenge $ hexdump -C fileA
00000000  57 30 6d 4d 68 55 63 52  52 6e 47 38 64 63 67 68  |W0mMhUcRRnG8dcgh|
00000010  45 34 71 76 6b 33 4a 41  39 6c 47 74 38 6e 44 6c  |E4qvk3JA9lGt8nDl|
00000020
```

The problem with my `grep` command is that it is returning any line that has more than 32 chars. How can I make it return **only lines with exactly 32 chars**. The issue for me is that I can't modify my regex to match on a line break, because there is no line break.

My expected output would be simply:

```
fileA:W0mMhUcRRnG8dcghE4qvk3JA9lGt8nDl
```

(note: this is for a challenge that I've already solved with my ugly solution, but in this scenario we can only use `grep` and piping or redirecting output is not allowed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works.  `^` denotes start of line, plus the `{32}` you already had, then a `$` for end of line.

```
$ cat fileA fileB
12345678901234567890123456789012
123456789012345678901234567890123
12345678901234567890123456789012
123456789012345678901234567890124
$ grep -E "^.{32}$" fileA fileB
fileA:12345678901234567890123456789012
fileB:12345678901234567890123456789012
$
```

And as pointed out by @steeldriver, posix grep includes -x, so the following approach also works : `grep -xE ".{32}" fileA fileB`

Comment: POSIX grep should also support the `-x` or `--line-regexp` whole-line match, I think

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GNU Grep documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Introduction):

> If the final byte of an input file is not a newline, grep silently supplies one.

So, if you're using GNU grep, you should be able to use the beginning-of-line/end-of-line anchors (`^` and `$`) as usual, even if you're not working on properly-formed plaintext files.

```
grep '^.\{32\}$' fileA fileB
```